# Wireguard causing Bonjour to fail

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, wireguard, bonjour

I rely on the following Wireguard VPN to gain IPv6 access on a Windows PC

```ini
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <private-key>
Address = fd24:609a:6c18::2/64

[Peer]
PublicKey = <public-key>
AllowedIPs = fd24:609a:6c18::/64, 2000::/3
Endpoint = <server-ipv4-addr>
```

and I found out that this connection is causing Bounjor service to fail to start and complain

```
Windows could not start the Bonjour Service service on Local Computer.
Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly
```

Why is `2000::/3` interfering with Bonjour which should be only concerned about local addresses?

The routing table isn't showing anything related to `2000::/3` though

```
IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
 72      5 fd24:609a:6c18::/64      On-link
 72    261 fd24:609a:6c18::2/128    On-link
 18    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 17    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 51   5256 fe80::/64                On-link
 17    281 fe80::42d:f7a7:6283:5093/128
                                    On-link
 18    281 fe80::4c7c:3a3a:2101:2679/128
                                    On-link
 51   5256 fe80::57b2:dc59:7d26:b5d8/128
                                    On-link
 21    286 fe80::8c49:ded0:8a8f:8598/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
 18    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 17    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
 51   5256 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
```

which could be related to the issue.

Comment: How do you know it's the `2000::/3` that's causing the crash?

Comment: @u1686_grawity Because I have tried deleting `2000::/3` so `fd24:609a:6c18::/64` is the only allowed IPs and then Bonjour service is able to start.

Comment: Do you have multicast enabled on the WireGuard interface? Try adding `224.0.0.251/32` and `ff02::fb/128` multicast addresses to allowed IP.

Comment: @harrymc No, but adding them to the allowed IPs doesn't make a difference. Why am I supposed to add them to the allowed IPs though? Doesn't that mean routing Bonjour traffic which us supposed to be local through the VPN?